# NetLocalGroupGetMembers returns different members number according to LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO value

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

I'd like to retrieve the number of users belonging to some Windows UserGroup.
From the documentation of the Python API :

```
win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(server, group, *level*)
```

I understand that according to the *level* param, I'll get differently detailed data, corresponding to Windows  LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_0,  LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_1,  LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_2 or  LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_3 structures.

Thus, if 93 users belong to the specified userGroup, I expect to **always** get 93 objects/structures of one of those types.

But my results are quite different. Here's what I get

```
>>> import win32net
>>> import win32api
>>> server = "\\\\" + win32api.GetComputerName()
>>> users = []
>>> group = u"MyGroup"
>>> (users, total, res) = win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(server, group, 0)
>>> len(users)
93
>>> (users, total, res) = win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(server, group, 1)
>>> len(users)
56
>>> (users, total, res) = win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(server, group, 2)
>>> len(users)
39
>>> (users, total, res) = win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(server, group, 3)
>>> len(users)
68
```

I expect to get 93 users. And then I want the 93 usernames. 
The username is accessible when specifying level=1 and with that param, only 56 are returned.

Any clue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The call returns different numbers of results due to the size of the data for the requested level.
You can use the returned resume handle to continue fetching the rest, or increase the buffer size to get all results in one call.

Here's the full parameter list from the pywin32 help file:
NetLocalGroupGetMembers(server, groupName , level , resumeHandle , prefLen )

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help.

Here's the result :-)

```
import win32net
import win32api
import win32netcon

server = "\\\\" + win32api.GetComputerName()
users = []
result = []
group = "MyGroup"
handle = 0
level = 1
while True:
    (users, total, handle2) = win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(server, group,
                                level, handle, win32netcon.MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH)
    for u in users:
        result.append(u)
    if handle2 == 0:
        break
    else:
        handle = handle2
print len(result)
```

Comment: Great answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Sun Wikong's answer, I made a pip package to get user membership among alot of other functions.

Install with `pip install windows_tools.users`

Usage:

```
import windows_tools.users as users

# We use group SID instead of name so we get actual results regardless of system locale
# You can use well_known_sids() for translation, eg
# sid = well_known_sids(username='Administrators')
# or
# usernname = well_known_sids(sid='S-1-5-32-545')


members = users.get_local_group_members(group_sid='S-1-5-32-545')
for member in members:
    print(member)
```

You might also want to check if a user is local admin:

```
# if no user is given, current one is used
is_admin = is_user_local_admin('myuser')
print(is_admin)
```